# CS/Bioinformatics degree

Tags: computer-science, bioinformatics

I am a college student and I am trying to decide what degree I should pursue. I love Computer Science and I am also interested in learning about biology. I am keen on having a software development job. I love the crazy unhealthy stressful life of start ups for now, but I also would like a stable job for the long run. Luckily my school offers a degree in CS with specification in bioinformatics. I am concerned on whether such degree would put me at a disadvantage in programming jobs or bioinformatics research as opposed to others who have pure CS degree or pure bioinformatics degrees. Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about career advice, not programming. Your question might be on-topic at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [The Workplace](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: see http://www.biostars.org/show/questions/

Comment: You didn't read the [jobs] tag, did you?

Comment: Nope, I didn't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a degree in underwater basketweaving, it wouldn't matter.

What matters more is that you (A) can learn whatever mess of a system your future employer uses, and (B) actually spend time in a corporate environment.

To accomplish part A, learn the concepts of programming, and how the computer actually processes data. At that point every new language you're faced with will be the same thing all over again just with a different syntax, and you'll be mostly ready to map concepts from familiar languages to the new language.

Then part B... you will probably need to do some stepping-stone co-op type jobs before you get to the "good" ones. Startup culture does not map well into a larger corporation and vice-versa. Experience cannot be taught in a class or described adequately in a book. Some important things to keep in mind: Willingness to adapt to a new culture, being okay with not seeing the whole picture when given a direction, and respecting the people who have been there longer than you.

If you have an employer in mind, ask them what they want to see in a new hire. Look at job descriptions in your target field now while you aren't yet looking for a job. Aim to learn those things.

Good luck!